# Подмена браузером HTTP/1.0 на HTTP/1.1 в ответе сервера

Tags: python, windows, http, браузер

Простейший web сервер на `python` (python2.7, windows10):

```
python -mSimpleHTTPServer
```

Отдает статичные файлы. `curl` показывает, что используется протокол `HTTP/1.0` (что соответствует документации HTTPServer):

```
curl -s -D - http://localhost:8000/foo.jpg -o nul
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.11
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 07:21:20 GMT
Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 25803
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 06:13:58 GMT
```

В то же время при запросе через браузер (Crome, Firefox), получается `HTTP/1.1` (видно через консоль разработчика, на вкладке `network`):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: SimpleHTTP/0.6 Python/2.7.11
Date: Sun, 07 Aug 2016 07:21:42 GMT
Content-type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 25803
Last-Modified: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 06:13:58 GMT
```

Соответственно браузер не закрывает соединение после запроса.

В обоих случаях вывод с помощью `print` в исходниках `BaseHTTPServer.py` показывает первую строку запроса клиента как `GET /foo.jpg HTTP/1.1`. В ответе в обоих случаяx (также по `print` в коде сервера) первая строка: `HTTP/1.0 200 OK`.

Прокси сервер не используется.

Если запрашивать с браузера из виртуальной машины, то версия http не меняется (остается `HTTP/1.0`).

С чем может быть связано такое различие?

Comment: Прокси-сервера не настроено? Проверьте настройки браузера.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не пользовался прокси, сейчас проверил на всякий случай ещё раз

Comment: Браузер сам выбирает 1.1 или 1.0 использовать

Comment: @andreymal с установкой шел или установился позже, лежит в `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\http\client.py`

Comment: @VladimirGamalian это как-то очень-очень-очень странно, ибо во втором питоне он обязан быть модулем [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) (свой коммент по неосторожности удалил, но модуля http.server у себя так и не нашёл)

Comment: @andreymal SimpleHTTPServer то же есть, как обычно. У меня 2.7.11, может в качестве плавного перехода туда воткнули вещи из третьего

Comment: А если запускать в Python 3.5 (там модуль http.server таки есть), то мой Firefox юзает HTTP/1.0

Comment: @VladimirGamalian у меня тоже 2.7.11, но почему-то всё равно нет

Comment: То что код: `http.server` работает вместо `SimpleHTTPServer` указывает, что команда `python` у вас запускает Python 3, а не Python 2 (сервер http/1.0 в любом случае). Правда, Server http-заголовок указывает, что Python 2 код исполняется. Либо у вас другой код исполняется либо окружение нестандартное (что `sys.version`, `http.server.__file__` показывает?)

Comment: @jfs @anreymal установлен пакет `future`, в нем есть адаптер-переходник https://github.com/PythonCharmers/python-future/blob/master/src/http/client.py

Comment: @VladimirGamalian или у вас `six` установлен или ещё что-то—важно что не из stdlib. Предпочтительно, создавать минимальные самодостаточные примеры такие как `py -mSimpleHTTPServer`, чтобы ясно было какой код исполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Виновником оказался ESET Smart Security 9.
Как оказалось, отключения через `Приостановить работу файервола (разрешить весь трафик)` было не достаточно. В детальных настройках была обнаружена опция:

[image: картинка]

При отключении которой протокол перестал трансформироваться в http1.1.

Comment: Владимир, если вам будет интересно, в попытке ответить вам, я задал подобный вопрос на SO и получил исчерпывающий ответ по этой теме
http://stackoverflow.com/q/38813071/4569475

Comment: @DmitryPetukhov ага, почитал, спасибо!

Comment: @DmitryPetukhov у вас отличающийся вопрос: у вас клиент посылает http/1.1 запрос, а сервер возвращает http/1.0 ответ (в логе у вас запрос клиента, а не ответ). Здесь же похоже программулина от eset молча втиснулась между браузером и сервером (в качестве прокси) и поэтому браузер видит http/1.1 ответ (`http.server` возвращает http/1.0 во всех рассматриваемых случаях)